# Book Identification: Cyborg... Mercenary.. Space routes maybe

Tags: story-identification, books, robots, bounty-hunters

I am trying to identify a book based on a few scattered details.

There is a cyborg bounty hunter and/or mercenary that experiences some form of discomfort with his cybernetics (possibly the temperature of the cybernetics being uncmfortable)

there are slime-aliens of some sort, and it is possible a character from the story takes l overs from this species. This species may be acidic, and a character may have lost his legs to one.

There is a psychic alien in the book, who may be small, that apparently drank something at one point that was supposed to be poisonous (maybe) but just made him/her drunk.

One of the primary conflicts of the book seems to be that an robot (possibly ancient, and possibly with six arms) is destroying interstellar pathways it created (may be wormholes, may be stargates, may simply be paths of some sort)

The only other details that can be recalled... are that there is some sort of translator box, and some other sort of device with a nuclear/atomic battery.

The book would most likely have been published before the year 2001

And it definitely has a lot of aspects that make it seem like a post-star-wars science fiction story...

Comment: _apparently drank something at one point that was supposed to be poisonous_... And _apparently_. Someone else has told you these details and you don't really believe them? How is anyone here supposed to find this book if you do't even beleibe the account you're giving us?

Comment: Hey man... you dont have to be rude about my poor word choices okay. I just cant garuntee things happened that way...

Comment: Not trying to be rude a all, just trying to help you out. It's easier for everyone if the question is as straight forward and understandable as possible.

Comment: Sorry, I am just trying to provide as much information as is available.

Comment: Maybe the Last Legionary series by Douglas Hill?
http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/LastLegionary


https://www.librarything.com/series/Last+Legionary

Comment: nope... sorry...

Answer (score 2):

I think you're talking about the *[Mag Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_of_the_Guardians)* books by Margaret Weis.  The main character was called Xris Cyborg. He has a companion named The Little One who "is a formidable telepath".